# DevilBox change ./log/

Tags: logging, devilbox

Could anybody tell me how I can change the default log directory `./log/` to something else?  Is there any variable I can set in .env?

Thanks for your help.

E.

Comment: RTFM: "You can also change the behaviour where logs are streamed by setting DOCKER_LOGS to 1 inside your .env file. When doing logs are sent to Docker logs." (https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intermediate/read-log-files.html)

Comment: OK, @Luuk, thanks for your input but even so I re-read the doc after your nice comment, I still don't see a response to my question.  To rephrase it, I don't want the logs to be streamed to docker logs nor to the ./log directory but to something like /var or ~/foo or ./bar  How can I do that?